# How to extract the table name from a CREATE/UPDATE/INSERT statement in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, regex, parsing, google-bigquery, data-extraction

I am trying to parse the table being created, inserted into or updated from the following sql queries stored in a table column.

Let's call the table column `query`. Following is some sample data to demonstrate variations in how the data could look like.

```
with sample_data as (
  select 1 as id, 'CREATE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 2 as id, 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 3 as id, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1; CREATE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 4 as id, 'INSERT /*some comment*/ INTO tbl2 ...' as query union all
  select 5 as id, 'INSERT /*some comment*/ INTO tbl2 ...' as query union all
  select 6 as id, 'UPDATE tbl3 SET col1 = ...' as query union all
  select 7 as id, '/*some garbage comments*/ UPDATE tbl3 SET col1 = ...' as query union all  
  select 8 as id, 'DELETE tbl4 ...' as query
),
```

Following are the formats of the queries (we are trying to extract **`table_name`** ):

**#1**
    `some optional statements like drop table`
    CREATE `some comments or optional statement like OR REPLACE` TABLE **`table_name`**
    `everything else`

**#2**
    `some optional statements like drop table`
    INSERT `some comments` INTO `some comments` **`table_name`**

**#3**
    `some optional statements like drop table`
    UPDATE `some comments` **`table_name`**
    `everything else`

Comment: "I am", "we are"? And what did you/you try so far? Where did you fail?

Comment: My regex experience is limited to LIKE '%%' statements. Can you help?

Comment: Neither SQL nor its LIKE operator are regular expressions. Stack Overflow is for asking advice, not delegating work to be done. You didn't even approach the problem.

Comment: so based on shown data, what is expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

`(?:(?:CREATE(?:(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+OR(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+REPLACE)?|DROP)(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+TABLE(?:(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+IF(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+EXISTS)?|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+INTO)(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+([^\s\/*;]+)`

### *"Show your working"*...

To construct a suitable regex, let's start with the following relatively simple/readable version:

`((CREATE( OR REPLACE)?|DROP) TABLE( IF EXISTS)?|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT INTO) ([^\s\/*;]+)`

All the spaces above could be replaced with "at least one whitespace character", i.e. `\s+`. But we also need to allow comments. For a comment that looks like `/*anything*/` the regex looks like `\/\*.*\*\/` *(where the comment characters are escaped with `\` and "anything" is the `.*` in the middle)*. Given there could be multiple such comments, optionally separated by whitespace, we end up with `(\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+`. Plugging this in everywhere there was a space gives:

`((CREATE((\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+OR(\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+REPLACE)?|DROP)(\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+TABLE((\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+IF(\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+EXISTS)?|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT(\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+INTO)(\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+([^\s\/*;]+)`

One further refinement needs to be made: Bracketed expressions have been used for choices, e.g. `(CHOICE1|CHOICE2)`. But this syntax includes them as capturing groups. Actually we only require one capturing group for the table name so we can exclude all the other capturing groups via `?:`, e.g. `(?:CHOICE1|CHOICE2)`. This produces the regex given above under "TL;DR".

### Online Regex Demo

Here's a demo of it working with your examples: [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrkHp0/7)

### SQL

The Google BigQuery documentation for [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) says it will return the substring matched by the capturing group. So I'd expect something like this to work:

```
with sample_data as (
  select 1 as id, 'CREATE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 2 as id, 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 3 as id, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1; CREATE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 4 as id, 'INSERT /*some comment*/ INTO tbl2 ...' as query union all
  select 5 as id, 'INSERT /*some comment*/ INTO tbl2 ...' as query union all
  select 6 as id, 'UPDATE tbl3 SET col1 = ...' as query union all
  select 7 as id, '/*some garbage comments*/ UPDATE tbl3 SET col1 = ...' as query union all  
  select 8 as id, 'DELETE tbl4 ...' as query
)

SELECT
  *, REGEXP_EXTRACT(query, r"(?:(?:CREATE(?:(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+OR(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+REPLACE)?|DROP)(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+TABLE(?:(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+IF(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+EXISTS)?|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+INTO)(?:\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*?)*\s+([^\s\/*;]+)") AS table_name
FROM sample_data;
```

*(The above is untested so please let me know in the comments if there are any issues.)*

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on your data, but you might find some success using an approach like this:

```
with data as (
  select 1 as id, 'CREATE TABLE tbl1 ...' as query union all
  select 2 as id, 'INSERT INTO tbl2 ...' as query union all
  select 3 as id, 'UPDATE tbl3 ...' as query union all
  select 4 as id, 'DELETE tbl4 ...' as query
),
splitted as (
  select id, split(query, ' ') as query_parts from data
)
select
  id,
  case 
    when query_parts[safe_offset(0)] in('CREATE', 'INSERT') then query_parts[safe_offset(2)]
    when query_parts[safe_offset(0)] in('UPDATE', 'DELETE') then query_parts[safe_offset(1)]
    else 'Error'
  end as table_name
from splitted
```

Of course this depends on the cleanliness and syntax in your `query` column.  Also, if your table_name is qualified with `project.table.dataset` you would need to do further splitting.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your answer. This is a great start. It made me realize that I should have added a sample dataset to start with. 

The current solution covers some of the cases but I updated the question with sample data (in your format) to reflect some edge cases.

Would really appreciate if you can suggest a solution to incorporate these variations.

Answer (score 1):

select CHARINDEX('INSERT', Sql_text) + 7,CHARINDEX('INTO', Sql_text)+4,
case when CHARINDEX('(', Sql_text)>0 then CHARINDEX('(', Sql_text) else CHARINDEX('select', Sql_text) end,
CHARINDEX('INTO ', Sql_text),
SUBSTRING(Sql_text, CHARINDEX('INTO ', Sql_text)+4 , (case when CHARINDEX('(', Sql_text)>0 then CHARINDEX('(', Sql_text) else CHARINDEX('select', Sql_text) end)
-(CHARINDEX('INTO ', Sql_text)+4) )
from insert_tracker

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach with use of [ML.GENERATE_TEXT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-generate-text)

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_table_names(text STRING) AS ((
SELECT TRIM(STRING(ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content']), '" ')
  FROM ML.GENERATE_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_llm`,
  (SELECT FORMAT('''
    In provided SQL text - extract the table names from a CREATE/UPDATE/INSERT statement in an SQL query. 
    Do not provide any comments, explanations. Just show table names mentioned in the query: %s''', text)  AS prompt)
)));
SELECT query, get_table_names(query) AS table_names
FROM sample_data
```

if applied to sample data like in your question

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'CREATE TABLE tbl1 ...' AS query UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tbl1 ...' AS query UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl1; CREATE TABLE tbl2 ...' AS query UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'INSERT /*some comment*/ INTO tbl2 ...' AS query UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, 'INSERT /*some comment*/ INTO tbl2 ...' AS query UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS id, 'UPDATE tbl3 SET col1 = ...' AS query UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS id, '/*some garbage comments*/ UPDATE tbl3 SET col1 = ...' AS query UNION ALL  
  SELECT 8 AS id, 'DELETE tbl4 ...' AS query
)
```

output is

[image]