How to do a text ChatGPT-like text prompt in bigquery
Take the following prompt from ChatGPT to provide context:

Is there a (simple) way in BigQuery to construct a ChatGPT-like response based on data in the row? As a simplistic example:
with tbl as (
  select "Mike" as first_name, "Davis" as last_name, "Dinner" as event, TIMESTAMP "2024-07-04 19:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" as time UNION ALL
    select "Thomas" as first_name, "Keller" as last_name, "Dinner" as event, TIMESTAMP "2024-07-04 19:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" as time

) SELECT *, 
  'Send a message to "' || first_name || ' ' || last_name || '" about a "' || event || '" event at time "' || time || '"' AS prompt
  generate_gpt(prompt)
FROM tbl

Is there any way to do something similar?


see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77212891/5221944, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250914/5221944, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247507/5221944, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77434838/5221944

You will need to create a remote connection first, which is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/llm-with-vertex-ai-only-using-sql-queries-in-bigquery, starting in Step 5.
Once you do that, you can generate a model:
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL test.llm_model
  REMOTE WITH CONNECTION `us.vertex`
  OPTIONS (remote_service_type = 'CLOUD_AI_LARGE_LANGUAGE_MODEL_V1');

Give it permissions from IAM and then do a query such as the following:
with tbl as (
  select "Mike" as first_name, "Davis" as last_name, "Dinner" as event, TIMESTAMP "2024-07-04 19:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" as time UNION ALL
  select "Thomas" as first_name, "Keller" as last_name, "Dinner" as event, TIMESTAMP "2024-07-04 19:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" as time
)
SELECT
  prompt,
  ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content'] AS generated_text,
FROM
  ML.GENERATE_TEXT(
    MODEL `test.llm_model`,
    (SELECT 'Generate a text message to "' || first_name || ' ' || last_name || '" about a "' || event || '" event at time "' || time || '". Make sure the time is converted from UTC to PST.' AS prompt from tbl)


Pretty neat! The time is even converted properly to PST.
